# Gson deserialise - avoid wrapper class

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I am trying to deserialize the following JSON using Gson in Kotlin.

```
{
  "things": [
    {
      "name": "Thing1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Thing2"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I currently have 2 classes I'm deserializing into;

1. ThingWrapper - Has one property, 'Things' that is a List
2. Thing - Has a name property

In my service, I am simply returning the `List<Thing>` from 'things' and never exposing the ThingWrapper.

```
fun getThings(): List<Thing> {
   return Gson().fromJson(json, ThingWrapper::class.java).things
}
```

My question is can I use Gson to deserialize in a way that can avoid the need for a `ThingWrapper` class entirely?

Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: if you are using Retrofit & Gson to parse this JSON, remove the ThingWrapper.class and pass List of things, so it will parse only things

Comment: @AkshayKatariya I am not currently using Retrofit, I am purposely trying to solve this problem in Gson directly.
Just to confirm though are you saying that in Retrofit you can pre-parse the response to only extract the array?

Comment: yes you can eliminate the parameter you don't want and it will parse only those parameter present in ur POJO, I think you can try with Gson as well

Comment: Thank you I will remember that when I begin to use Retrofit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to eliminate the Wrapper class you can use `JSONObject` class to parse the object and then extract JSON array from it.

```
val things: List<Thing> = Gson().fromJson(
            JSONObject(json).getJSONArray("things").toString(),
            object : TypeToken<List<Thing>>() {}.type)
Log.i("output", things.toString())
```

> I/output: [Thing(name=Thing1), Thing(name=Thing2)]

This worked for me.